# How to support Connection Pool vendor specific DataSourceProperties configurations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration`:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
public HikariDataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
    HikariDataSource dataSource = createDataSource(properties, HikariDataSource.class);
    if (StringUtils.hasText(properties.getName())) {
        dataSource.setPoolName(properties.getName());
    }
    return dataSource;
}
```

The parameter type `DataSourceProperties` lacks many of the properties that is supported by the target type `HikariDataSource` (e.g. `maximum-pool-size` and many others) (aparently by design). and hence many of the properties is not passed as documented in : `spring-configuration-metadata.json`

```
{
  "name": "spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit",
  "type": "java.lang.Boolean",
  "sourceType": "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource"
},
{
  "name": "spring.datasource.hikari.catalog",
  "type": "java.lang.String",
  "sourceType": "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource"
}
```

So should I define the dataasource bean and set the properties to `HikariDataSource` so what is the point of having properties such as the above (`spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit`... etc) the as part of the autoconfiguration properties?

Comment: Do you have any limitation to not use the spring.datasource.hikari props supported by SpringBoot?

Comment: It doesn't work with me, and when I dig into the code I didn't understand how it is bound.this is why I am asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HikariDataSource` extends `HikariConfig`, which has all the additional properties you would want to set.

Spring will bind any property with the prefix `spring.datasource.hikari` into the `DataSource` directly, not into the `DataSourceProperties` object.

It is done by using `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor` in a later stage.

Comment: According to javadoc of `DataSourceBuilder` the class used to do the binding: "To inject additional properties into the result you can downcast it, or use {@code @ConfigurationProperties}." but I cannot see the binding of the vendor the additional properties in the code or can find its effect at the runtime.

Comment: Not sure what that note in the JavaDoc is trying to to indicate, but in my experience the `DataSourceProperties` do not get the Hikari specific properties, only the top level params that apply to all data source types.

Comment: Yes this is what I trying to say iny queation... so why we have such spring autoconfiguration properties for vendor props (hikari for example)?

Comment: The properties *do* get passed to the vendor specific pool, they're just not inside the standard Spring `DataSourceProperties`. In the case of Hikari, they get set on the `HikariDataSource` because it extends `HikariConfig`.

Comment: Yea, I finally found the BeanPostProcessor that do the binding which is `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor` Thanks!